# Is there a UTXO for IOTA?

Tags: utxo, iota

How does the cryptocurrency IOTA keep record of the spent coins? Is there something similar to the UTXO where the unspent coins were recorded?

And it somebody wants to spend a coin, do you have to search through the whole tangle?